# How to prove the existence of non-intersecting subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\Bbb R^n$, $P,P'$ two $k$-dim subspaces, there must exist a $(n-k)$-dim subspace $Q$ whose intersection with both $P$ and $P'$ is zero.

Although I have no idea how to prove this result, I feel it might be somehow connected to [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26/64010).

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** I tried arguing analogously to Steve's answer to the linked problem, but I was just not sure how to make a proper analogy, or these two problems are not actually related at all. By the way, geometric intuition tells me the result is still true for any finite collection of $k$-dim subspaces.

Comment: Can you extract the three dimensional case for $\Bbb R^n$ $n \ge 4$ to show it. Like $\Bbb R ^3$ is a subspace and just show it is true for $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @marshalcraft I can't visualise $n\ge4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than look at a set of subspaces, you might look at the space $\def\R{\Bbb R}(\R^n)^{n-k}$ of $n-k$-tuples of vectors, each of which span a subspace that is a candidate for$~Q$ (some of them are linearly dependent, in which case $Q$ would not have the right dimension, but these $n-k$-tuples are among the ones that we are going to exclude). Fixing some basis of$~P$, we can complete those fixed $k$ vectors with our varying $n-k$-tuple and compute the determinant, giving a polynomial function $f:(\R^n)^{n-k}\to\R$ (in fact an $n-k$-linear alternating one) that is not identically zero (since $P$ certainly does have complementary subspaces). Now the "good" $n-k$-tuples are those for which $f$ does not vanish, and these form an open dense subset of $(\R^n)^{n-k}$. A similar construction for $P'$ gives another open dense subset, and the intersection of the two [is still open and dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143211/intersection-of-two-open-dense-sets-is-dense). In particular it is not empty, and the span of any $n-k$-tuple taken from it gives a$~Q$.

This argument immediately generalises to any finite set of $k$-dimensional subspaces to which one seeks a common complementary subspace.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is brilliant because it kind of "topologises" the problem without explicitly introducing Grassmannian. A minor question: what is $W$?

Comment: $W$ was me thinking this was a more suitable name for a subspace than $Q$. But I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you again! I have to admit that this is definitely one of the most beautiful proofs I have ever read!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying fact here is that subspaces $X$ of codimension $k$ in $V={\mathbb R}^n$ form a manifold called the *Grassmannian* $Gr(V,k)$, whose dimension is easily computed.  The condition that a given $X\in Gr(V,k)$ should have nontrivial intersection with $P$ is a positive-codimension condition (also easily computed). Thus you have two positive-codimension subvarieties in $Gr$ defined by $P$ and $P'$ and it suffices to choose a point not in one of those subvarieties (this would work for any finite number of $P$'s and in fact even for a countable number of them).

Comment: Well I suppose this is exactly what I'm coming from... I need the result to prove in the construction of the Grassmannian.

Comment: Choosing a basis for $V$ extending that of $P$ one can write down the condition of nontrivial intersection with $P$ as a linear condition and then the result will follow by dimension count via linear algebra.

Comment: But under a basis thus obtained $P'$ need not have a good basis representation. I think at least we must take both $P,P'$ into consideration simultaneously.

Comment: No, the point is *not* to deal with them simultaneously. For $P$ we show that the exceptional set has dimension that's too small.  The argument is the same for $P'$.  Their interaction among them is irrelevant.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed arguments? For instance what do you mean by "linear condition" for non-trivial intersection? Even if we know the basis of $Q$, how do we further determine if it has non-trivial intersection with $P$ by simple linear conditions?

Comment: You can represent a subspace of codimension $k$ by an $(n-k)$-tuple of vectors (there is of course redundancy here which needs to be figured into the dimension calculations). Requiring this to intersect nontrivially with the standard $k$-dimensional subspace of Euclidean $n$-space gives a positive-codimension condition on the matrix formed by the $(n-k)$ vectors.

Comment: The conditions I am thinking of are of the form of an upper bound for the rank of a (sub)matrix. These are of course not linear conditions but rather conditions easily expressible in terms of linear algebra.